# How to assign the first element context with default value?

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-class

I am using the follwing code to display some values from the array

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" *ngFor="let card of cards; let i=index">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Card {{card.id}}</h3>
      <p>{{card.text}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I would like to set the first one is a button with given hard code text. It shouldn't from the array.
I think that probably using `ngClass` to compare when the index is 0. But not sure how?

Comment: what do you mean with button with given hard code text?

Comment: I want it click able so I thought it should be button. But if the div is clickable, then you can ignore the button requirement. Just a different text on div.

Comment: why not have another "card"<div> right above the ngFor loop? So whenever u do not need that hardcoded button, you can just remove it

Comment: @ByronWong, I want the cards side by side which like a matrix. Create another div is hard to align them.

Comment: Yes, meaning that it would be like 
<div class="row">
    <div class="column"> ( hardcoded card here )</div>
    <div class="column" ngFor...>
</div>

which then it should already be side by side since its under "row" class and you are repeating each "column" level div

Answer (score 0):

`Angular` has the `first` and `last` [variables](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/) out of the box.
I can't clearly understand what you are asking, but I think you want to show a button only on the first? You can also target the last like below.

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="column" *ngFor="let card of cards; let i=index let first = first; let last = last">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Card {{card.id}}</h3>
      <p>{{card.text}}</p>
        <ng-container *ngIf="first"><button>first item only</button></ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="last"><button>last item only</button></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I want is the first's face same as the rest cards. The first one is just a button with default text. The others are cards from array. The dimensions should be same.

Comment: ah, then in that case I think Byron was on to it in the comments above, create a static card and add it before the ngFor, bootstrap will wrap automatically

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" *ngFor="let card of cards; let i=index">
    <div 
      class="card" 
     (click)="((i === 0) || (i === cards.length)) && yourClickEvent($event)"
    >
      <h3>Card {{ (i === 0) ? 'Your Hard code ID' : card.id }}</h3>
      <p>{{card.text}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The condition in the click event above, will check if its either the first or last card and then implement your click functionality.. so is the case with the ID

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am not sure. But I have a demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sg5z9c?file=src/app/app.component.html